# How to speed up matrix processing by Cython and Multiprocessing?

Tags: cython, python-multiprocessing

I have a NxM matrix. I need to update each entries of that matrix following some conditions. Then I have to repeat this process many times. To gain some speed I coded it in Cython. My basic code structure uses the nested loop as follows-

```
for itr in range(1,20000):
   for n in range(N):    #rows of the matrix
      for m in range(M): #Column of the matrix
         <Update matrix[n,m]>
```

Unfortunately this is not fast enough. There I tried the parallel processing. Code structure looks as-

```
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
for itr in range(1,20000):

   with nogil, parallel():
      for n in prange(N):    #rows of the matrix
         for m in prange(M): #Column of the matrix
            <Update matrix[n,m]>
```

But this turns out to be 1.5 times ***slower*** than the Cython version!! Whole code is given below. (I had to turn on the gil inside the nested for loop for checking some conditions).

How to correctly use/code multiprocessing in order gain some speed? (I use Anaconda in windows)

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange

def MatrixUpdate(int[:,:] Matrix,beta):
    cdef int itr, n,m
    cdef float test
    cdef int N=np.shape(Matrix)[0]
    cdef int M=np.shape(Matrix)[1]


    for itr in range(1,20000):
        with nogil, parallel():
            for n in prange(N):
                for m in prange(M):
                    test=2*Matrix[n,m]*(Matrix[(n+1)%N,m%M]+Matrix[n%N,(m-1)%M]+Matrix[n%N,(m+1)%M]+Matrix[(n-1)%N,m%M])
                    with gil:          #Here I have to use numpy which cannot be called without gil.
                        if test<=0:                
                            Matrix[n,m]=-Matrix[n,m]
                        elif np.exp(-test*beta)>np.random.rand():
                            Matrix[n,m]=-Matrix[n,m]     
    return Matrix

InitMatrix=np.random.choice([-1,1],size=(200,200))
FinalMatrix=MatrixUpdate(InitMatrix,0.5)
```

Comment: For a start only make the outer loop parallel. Realistically the`with gil` section is a big enough portion that it isn't likely to work. You could use `exp` from libc though

Comment: Also without passing openmp flags (which exactly depends on your compiler) prange won’t be executed in parallel. Multiprocessing has much more overhead, I would stick with openmp/prange.